# Converted BCD coded hexa Decimal value into readable date time

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcd

I have hexadecimal value like - 160413031849, which needs to be converted to valid Date time (something readable) like - April 13, 16th, 3:18:49.
So how I can do it with JS in nodeJS.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: It's a Unix datestamp - `new Date(value * 1000)`.